# Behind a proxy: Flask SQLAlchemy connect to Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I have a postgres instance running on a remote (AWS).

I am on a corporate network using a proxy. I can use the [`tsocks`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/tsocks) package to connect to the postgres instance through a `SOCKS5` proxy.

Is there anyway for me to force FlaskSql to do the interactions through the proxy?

#### Notes

- I have tried setting the proxy on the `requests` module and can get that to work.
- I have tried some things with the `PySocks` module, e.g [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019179/proxying-udp-over-socks5-proxy-in-python) without any good results. Can you set which socket SQLAlchemy uses?
- I have set `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` as well, but it is not enough for tcp connections.

Comment: Did you try to setup the `http_proxy` environment variable?

Comment: @SzymonP. Yes, I have tried setting `http_proxy` as well as https. But postgres interacts over tcp, so it needs other proxy settings.